# Email can not be sent in php

Tags: php, smtp

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
```

I would like to send email in php using **gmail SMTP server** and did change on **php.ini**(See above code). Also add **$host, $port, $username and $pw** into the **sendEmail.php**.

However, email still can not be sent out. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

**sendEmail.php**

```
 $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "username@googlemail.com";
 $password = "password";

 $email_to = "n.liu@the-imcgroup.com";
 $email_subject = "Test E-Mail";
 $email_body = "Email Body";

 if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body)){
    echo "The email was successfully sent.";
 } else {
    echo "The email was NOT sent.";
 }
```

?>

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things will very likely be much easier for you if you use a library like PHPMailer for this purpose:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Using this class will aid in setting proper headers, configuring addressing and ensuring better deliverability in general.

Here's an example connecting to the gmail SMTP just like you described:

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: +1 Also, if you're working in a framework, it may well have email functions built-in that serve a similar purpose to phpmailer.